# Regex not allow chars [ and ]

Tags: c#, .net, regex

As the titles says, im looking for a regex expression for .net validation controls that does not allow square brackets. Basically I have an input field where I don't want to allow [ and ]. Anything else is fine.

Comment: @KasperSkov: "Not matching square brackets" is very broad. This would allow for example: an empty string, a string consisting only of whitespace, a string containing only unusual symbols, etc... Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: @Mark Empty doesnt matter, as my RequiredValidation control will kick in. Same as for whitespace. I think :) Unusual symbols is fine as well, as [] is the only chars I wont allow.

Comment: @Mark Maybe ive misunderstood the whole "match" and "no match"? I want the error kicking in when a [ or ] is submitted.

Comment: @Kirill Updated the question a bit. Dont know what else to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - note use of `@` to avoid escaping the slashes:

```
@"[^\[\]]*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
"^[^\\[\\]]*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
^(?!.*?\[)(?!.*?]).*$
```

Comment: Kirill, ive noticed that is doesnt work with line break. Enviroment.Newline, "/n" or "/b" or what ever it is in textareas. Any idea whats wrong?